# Как узнать имя ограничения (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

(Использую MySQL)
Я хочу удалить ограничение, но мне нужно его имя
Вопрос: *Как узнать имя ограничения* (Я его не задавал явно), оно было
 генерировано. Спасибо.

Почему решил это сделать:
*Есть таблица, в которой есть FK*

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| w_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| w_name | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| w_ar   | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Но я не могу его удалить запросом:

```
ALTER TABLE work
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_work;
```

И в чем изюминка: *Когда ввожу запрос первый раз, то:*

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

*Когда ввожу запрос второй раз, то:*

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of '.\default_test\work' to '.\default_test\#sql2-1378-1' (errno: 152)
```

Comment: Ну так первый раз вы его удалили, следовательно во второй раз его уже нет, отсюда и ошибка. Когда в InnoDB возникают такие нечитаемые ошибки, то их нормальный вид можно посмотреть через `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Comment: @BOPOH @ВОРОН Но в таблице! При `DESC table` вот что `| w_ar   | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |` Может не очень понятно, но обозначение FK осталось

Comment: Правильно, вы удалили FK, но при его создании дополнительно создается и простой ключ, а вот его вы не удалили. Т.е. здесь уже надо не FK грохать, а простой индекс.

Comment: Спасибо.) А есть разница `DROP INDEX` или `DROP KEY`? И первый и второй случай работают.

Comment: В [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) `KEY` - это синоним для `INDEX`: `KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.` С другими базами не работал, возможно там есть разница

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;
```

покажет вам полный SQL для создания таблицы, включая имена констрейнтов.

Comment: Спасибо. Круто)